# SharePoint list group fields calculate the delta

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I am looking for a solution to calculate the delta between every month for items that were not created at the same time.  Please see the attached picture for an example see below.

[image]

I didn't find any solution

Comment: Sorry, your question isn’t clear enough. Show us what output you expect and where you expect to store these values, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to perform calculations on the data in the same column in a SharePoint List like an excel file. If you want to make a comparison, you can [export the list data to Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-to-excel-from-sharepoint-or-lists-bfb2ea48-6118-4fa9-abb6-cced9424e5d9) and compare it in an Excel file.